# Clearing up a prime numbers algorithm

Tags: python, filter, lambda

I was learning some python and come across this code to find all prime numbers up to an N number.

```
N = 20
nums = xrange(2, N)

for i in xrange(2,8):
    nums = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, nums)

print nums    # [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

The algo works correctly, just this `x == i or` part confuses me.

If I simply remove it for the result of `nums = filter(lambda x: x % i, nums)`

the output will be `[11, 13, 17, 19]`

however, the `or` statement implies that for the numbers `[2,3,4,5,6,7]` the code line is evaluated to:

```
filter(lambda x: x == i, nums)
```

and I don't know how this alone can produce `[2, 3, 5, 7]` which is part of the final output and is simply true. Can anyone please elaborate on this because I've been starting at this code for a while and can't get my head around it.

Comment: note that this only produces primes up to 11^2 (121).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you evaluate and examine the output of this code, you'll get a better idea of what exactly is going on in the program:

```
N = 20
nums = range(2, N)

for i in xrange(2, 8):
    print "NUMS:", nums
    new_nums = []
    for x in nums:
        print "CONDITION: x ({x}) == i ({i}) or x ({x}) % i({i}) == 0 ({x_mod_i})".format(x=x, i=i, x_mod_i=x % i)
        if x == i or x % i:
            print " => APPEND", x
            new_nums.append(x)
    nums = new_nums
    print "***********"

print nums    # [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation of a simple prime number sieve. The `lambda x: x == i or x % i` expression evaluates to `True` if `x == i` or if `x % i`. The `%` in `x % i` is the modulus operator, so if `x` is divisible by `i`, `x % i` is zero, which evaluates to `False` in the context of the expression.